# Selecting some kind of closest child with jQuery seems not to work

Tags: tabs, nested, children, closest

I try to implement a nested tab module the following way.

By clicking on a .tabs__menu item I want to get the next .tabs__contents to display the correct entry.

I've prepared a codepen with markup and leave out all unimportant code so don't be irritated that it's not working. I don't understand why the variable debug2 is 0 and debug3 is 1. I expect debug2 to be 1 as well since I expect the following expression should find the element. Can anyone help me with this?:

```
.find(".tabs__contents").not(".tabs__contents .tabs__contents");
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNLWQp

Thanks in advance and best wishes,
duc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have an assumption why it's not working. It seems that the .not method doesn't starts to search relatively from the given collection but globally. With this statement

```
.not(".tabs__contents .tabs__contents")
```

debug2 finds itself and exclude it from the collection thats why the length is 0.